# segmentation fault when compiling as FDPIC ELF

Tags: c, linux, arm, executable, elf

I have a simple c helloworld program.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   printf("Hello World!\n");
   return 0;
}
```

when I compile it normally ( `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc helloworld.c -o out.o`) it executes without any problems but when I try to compile it as an FDPIC elf ( `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -shared -fPIC -fPIE helloworld.c -o out.o`), it crashes.

```
$ qemu-arm -cpu cortex-a7 out.o
qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
 arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -shared -fPIC -fPIE helloworld.c -o out.o
```

builds a shared library. Shared libraries lack startup code and can't normally be executed.

Perhaps you wanted to build a PIE executable instead? If so, do this:

```
 arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -pie -fPIE helloworld.c -o out.pie
```

Comment: I want it to be dynamic exe (ET-DYN type) because my target platform doesn't have mmu and it can only execute elfs using its dynamic linker. I tested your solution and it worked in simulation but didn't work on my actual target (because of lack of mmu normal elfs cannot be executed)

Comment: and if a shared library doesn't have startup code, how FDPIC executable elfs are dynamic?